# nth-child doesnt apply background-color correctly in the table

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-tables

N-th child only applies the background-color to the 2nd child but doesnt continue. Take a look: https://snipboard.io/fnDY0r.jpg
Any ideas?
My HTML-table looks like this (sorry for the german) :

```
<table class="Tabellen" id="Oeffnungszeiten">
    <caption>Aktuelle Öffnungszeiten (Frühling/Sommer 2020) </caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Wochentag</th>
            <th>Uhrzeit</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Montag</td>
            <td>09.00 - 18.00 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Dienstag</td>
            <td>09.00 - 18.00 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mittwoch</td>
            <td>09.00 - 17.00 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Donnerstag</td>
            <td>09.00 - 20.00 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Freitag</td>
            <td>08.00 - 20.00 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>    
            <td>Samstag</td>
            <td>08.00 - 20.00 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sonntag</td>
            <td>10.00 - 20.00 </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My CSS:

```
tr:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add `background-color` for **every** 2nd child (every even child: 2, 4, 6...), you need to use `nth-child(even)`

Check out this [snippet](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_nth-child_odd_even) of `even`, `odd` selectors.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
nth-child(even)
```

or

```
nth-of-child(2n)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the color to repeat after every one row you need to use 2n or you can also pass even in the nth child.

```css
tr:nth-child(2n) {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table class="Tabellen" id="Oeffnungszeiten">
    <caption>Aktuelle Öffnungszeiten (Frühling/Sommer 2020) </caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Wochentag</th>
            <th>Uhrzeit</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Montag</td>
            <td>09.00 - 18.00 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Dienstag</td>
            <td>09.00 - 18.00 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mittwoch</td>
            <td>09.00 - 17.00 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Donnerstag</td>
            <td>09.00 - 20.00 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Freitag</td>
            <td>08.00 - 20.00 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>    
            <td>Samstag</td>
            <td>08.00 - 20.00 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sonntag</td>
            <td>10.00 - 20.00 </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```